# Input fields not lining up in Safari

Tags: html, css, input

I'm trying to get these two inputs directly inline with each other. Here is what I want them to look like and what they do look like in Chrome:

http://i.gyazo.com/40d8dc64a6875ff2bf2de58ee6008610.png

However, this is what they look like in Safari:

http://i.gyazo.com/7b832fcb5e99057b60151182fbc4b21a.png

They are about 1 or 2px off on the height for some reason.

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" /><input type="button" name="button" value="Sign-Up">
```

Here is my CSS:

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #555459;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 0;
}

input[type="button"] {
    font: normal;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    height: 50px;
}
```

No clue why it's a pixel off in Safari, thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the height of the `text` to 50px

Comment: From what you have posted, the height of the textbox and the height of the button are different. They should be the same @George

Comment: They are indeed different, so that leads to another question: why aren't they the same height with height: 50px? So confusing!

Comment: I straight up copied and pasted your code exactly and changed them both to 50px and it looks great on my end. Do you have any other CSS going on? @George

Comment: Just chucked it in a fiddle, still not looking great.. http://jsfiddle.net/y3ao31yb/1/ :/

Comment: Okay figured that part out, needed box-sizing: content-box;